# Peut-on être fier et humble à la fois ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, culture

J'ai, à plusieurs reprises, entendu des personnes dire, suite à, entre autres, une nomination, une remise de prix ou une décoration, qu'ils en « sont fiers » et qu'ils l'acceptent « avec humilité » (ou « en toute humilité »).

Comment cela est-il possible ? « Fier » et « humble », ne sont-ils pas des antonymes ?

Comment: *Fier* a plusieurs sens, dans l'exemple donné  (→ qui  éprouve une satisfaction justifiée par l'honneur qui lui est fait) n'est pas antonyme de *humble*.  Il peut être antonyme de humble quand il est employé dans le sens péjoratif où le mot est parfois employé (cf TLF « Qui affiche une supériorité souvent illusoire; qui affecte des airs hautains et méprisants. ».

Comment: *L'humilité est l'habit de gala que revêt la fierté quand elle est de sortie*, Jean-Paul Richter

Comment: @Damien : ++! Splendide!

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous Tu devrais faire une réponse de ce commentaire

Comment: @Evpok J'ai essayé de montrer au PO comment [améliorer sa question](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) en l'orientant vers une recherche sur le sens. La façon dont elle est posée peut faire dériver sur tout autre chose que la langue (c'est le cas désormais [sauf pour une réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40328/358)). Peut-être le PO n'est-il pas francophone, malgré un excellent français, s'il est anglophone il peut ne pas connaitre le sens du mot fier. Laissons-lui une chance d'améliorer sa question avant toute chose.

Answer (score 10):

Il ne s’agit pas de prendre les mots à la lettre, mais de manifester les émotions suscitées par l'événement  :

> — Je suis fier d’avoir réussi cette épreuve, d’avoir dépassé ce que je croyais ềtre mes  limites.
>
> — Je reste humble devant vous et devant la société, conscient que je dois cette réussite à ce que vous m’avez transmis.

---

<sup>*Complément suite aux diverses réponses*</sup>

La langue française n’est pas l’apanage des seuls académiciens, grammairiens et autres concepteurs de l’Éducation Nationale, elle est aussi le gagne pain des comédiens dont la mission principale est d’utiliser le reflet des mots, miroirs de l’âme autant que de l’esprit, afin de transmettre l’indicible — ici la simultanéité vécue des émotions, sensations et autres perceptions — que l’on ne peut exprimer qu’en séquence dans l’oralité … or dans la question, c’est un orateur — comme tout comédien qui s’exprime en public — que l’on écoute : « J'ai, à plusieurs reprises, entendu des personnes dire, … ».

L’antonymie n’est pas contradictoire lorsque [les origines émotionnelles ou sensibles des mots sont de sources différentes](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40329/848),

Comment: Oui, quand bien même seraient-ils des antonymes parfaits, rien n'interdit d'avoir des sentiments mêlés.

Comment: +1! Oui! et... pour poursuivre @jlliagre... : ni même d'écrire des oxymores.

Comment: @jlliagre — Ce n’est pas un mélange de sentiments, mais deux sources qui sont à l’origine : celle de la conscience de soi, puis celle transmise par les autres.

Comment: Je ne vois pas trop où tu veux en venir. Que deux sources différentes en soient à l'origine ne contredit pas le fait que deux sentiments (ou attitudes) distincts en résultent.

Comment: @jlliagre — *Mélange de sentiments,* en première lecture, m’apparait proche de  l'instabilité émotionnelle durant laquelle on passe d’un extrême à l’autre, chaque extrême ayant un nom différent. Ce qui est ressenti ici est moins proche des sentiments, impressions que l’on ne peut définir précisément, que des émotions clairement ressenties et identifiées.

Comment: Does  "... pas l'apanage des seuls ..." mean "...pas l'apanage seulement des..."?

Comment: @PapaPoule — Bien sûr,  le premier met l’accent sur ce qui suit, le second sur ce qui précède, si *mean* est un équivalent logique, monde de l’écrit. Peut-être que lire à haute voix les deux formulations vous fera sentir comment l’oralité organise les mots pour mettre l’accent sur un point particulier du discours

Answer (score 4):

À mon sens oui, en français on peut distinguer la fierté (qui peut être neutre, positive ou négative) et l'orgueil (toujours négatif).

En anglais, *pride* (et *proud*) peuvent être utilisé pour les deux sens et je pense qu'il est plus difficile de détacher l'orgueil de la fierté.

On ne peut pas être orgueilleux et humble en même temps, mais on peut être fier et humble.

Comment: Sisi! On peut : "*on s'indigne de l'orgueilleuse humilité d'un écrivain qui révèle ses turpitudes..."* sans dire les *"chefs d'ordres monastiques dont l'orgueilleuse humilité prétend aux...*" Et de nombreux autres non-oxymores.

Comment: @aCOSwt En quoi "*l'orgueilleuse humilité*" n'est pas un oxymore ?

Comment: Dire qu'on ne peut pas être dans le même temps et X et Y est une opinion gratuite (indémontrable). Dire que *être X ET Y* a un sens pour de nombreux *"bons"* auteurs est un fait indéniable. Après, dire quel sens est effectivement plus difficile. Il faut les lire pour cela.

Comment: @aCOSwt Un oxymore est une figure de style et a un sens, surtout quand elle est écrite par de "*bons*" auteurs... Au contraire, le fait qu'elle ne soit utilisée que dans la littérature est plutôt un bon indicateur que c'est une figure de style recherchée, à mon sens.

Comment: Attention [*proud*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proud) en anglais peut aussi être négatif ou positif. Et on emploie l'expression *proud and humble at the same time* aussi souvent qu'en français il me semble. Mais sinon bien sûr je pense que tu as raison il faut partir de la polysémie du mot fier.

Answer (score 3):

Selon moi, les concepts derrière ces deux mots font partie de registres différents.

- La fierté est un sentiment qu'on peut éprouver.
- L'humilité est un comportement qu'on peut adopter.

Les deux ne me semblent pas incompatibles.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101087/discussion-on-answer-by-mouviciel-peut-on-etre-fier-et-humble-a-la-fois).

Answer (score -1):

Les sentiments  de cette sorte, que l'on pourrait considérer comme ambigus, mais que l'on caractérisera parfois comme étant des sentiments mitigés,  proviennent tout simplement des réalités matérielles de l'existence, comme dans l'exemple qui sera utilisé à la fin du présent paragraphe, et des notions culturelles acquises, lesquelles peuvent être, plutôt qu'un concours de principes purs, seulement celui de principes contradictoires ou à caractère positif pour les uns et négatif pour les autres ;  on a souvent à considérer le pour et le contre d'une situation, d'une décision. Certaines des notions qui mènent notre existence  sont de cette nature. Par exemple, l'une des plus inéluctables des notions de cette catégorie, celle de la survie, dans le domaine de la médecine, explique des commentaires tels que « Il fut intimé de la triste et heureuse vérité qu'il sauverait sa vie au prix de l'amputation de sa jambe malade. ».

Les notions particulières considérées dans cette question (qui vise le contexte d'une nomination, d'une remise de prix ou d'une décoration) peuvent être celles du mérite ou de la grandeur. Le mérite personnel est souvent reconnu comme ayant deux sources, l'une vraiment personnelle et l'autre tout à fait extérieure, bien que souvent aussi ce point de vue soit discutable. L'aspect  moral que cela évoque peut être simplement celui de la fierté sans dérive négative, en particulier la dérive qui consiste à tomber facilement dans l'orgueil, ou au contraire ce peut être l'orgueil ; disons en passant que c'est un point de vue que peut-être on doit entièrement à la culture chrétienne mais qui de nos jours peut être admis comme étant un apanage de la fondation laïque de la culture prise globalement, et aussi un apanage de la moralité chrétienne, avec laquelle  rivalise la moralité laïque.

Sans plus de contexte qu'il n'en est fourni dans la question l'explication de l'apparente antinomie doit pouvoir se faire selon l'une ou l'autre de ces deux notions. La fierté est donc soit motivée par le mérite dans la réussite soit par la grandeur de la réussite. S'il s'agit de mérite,  plutôt que de s'expliquer par une position purement morale l'humilité s'explique, du fait de cette part d'effort qui n'est pas personnelle mais qui provient de l'extérieur, par la nécessité d'une prise en compte de quoi revient à qui, et elle réside donc dans la conscience que l'on ne fait que partager le mérite ; s'il s'agit de grandeur, l'humilité est justifiée sur la base de l'aspect purement moral que se laisser aller à l'orgueil reste une très mauvaise façon de se conduire.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101086/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-peut-on-etre-fier-et-humble-a-la-fois).